# Is it possible to restrict the signature of the file type extension on attachment object?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have came up with a scenario, where file type extension was renamed as .txt and uploaded - where as its actually a pdf. Is there any possibility to restrict the signature of file type on the attachment object ?

Code:

```
trigger RestrictFilesFromAttachment on Attachment (before insert) {
    set<String> setExtNotAllowed = new set<String> {'exe','html','xml','edi','dll','bin','cmd','com','cpl','inf1','ins','inx','isu','job','jse','lnk','msc','msi','msp','mst','paf','pif','ps1','reg','sct','shb','shs','u3p','vb','vbe','vbs','vbscript','ws','wsf'};
    for (Attachment attachment :Trigger.new){
        String strFilename = attachment.Name.toLowerCase();
        List<String> parts = strFilename.splitByCharacterType();
        if(setExtNotAllowed.Contains(parts[parts.size()-1]))
        {
            attachment.addError('Sorry..!! Salesforce has blocked this file format - could not be attached!!');
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Does that mean you only need to allow pdf files? Where is your code failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

Security is hard. There are several ways to get a better idea of what the file actually is, some require more work than others, but none of the methods are guaranteed to work.

## Long answer

As you've found out, file extensions don't really have much meaning. Their main use is to give programs and operating systems an extra hint about what to do with the file (e.g. which program do we need to use to open this file?). It's very easy to simply change the file extension to something else.

Provided that the program itself doesn't force you to use a particular file extension, as long as the data inside the file is the same, you could name your file almost anything you wanted. You can have `MyPDFFile.mp3`, and Adobe Acrobat Reader would still open it without issue (provided that it really is a pdf file).

It's also possible to have multiple extensions (.tar.gz comes to mind, which should be familiar to anyone who has compiled a program from its source code).

This is an issue that has plagued the internet at large for over a decade. As far as I know, there is no perfect solution. In the end, it comes down to two questions. *What information do I trust?* and *How much work am I willing to do?*

Generally speaking, when a file is uploaded, you have the following information about the file:

- The file name (including extension)
- The file's [mime type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)
- The file's length
- The file's raw, binary content

### What Information do I trust?

The name (and extension) of a file can be easily manipulated, so we can't trust that.

The mime type (which it appears Salesforce provides to us in the `ContentType` field of the `Attachment` SObject) is harder to manipulate, but this can still be done. I can't find any information on how Salesforce determines the mime type, so it's not a great idea to trust this information either.

The file length alone isn't too much help (and can be easily padded to increase the size).

The raw, binary content of the file is about the only thing that you can trust here. It's also the hardest to work with.

### The hard (but arguably better) way

About the easiest time you can have here, working with the raw content of the attachment, is to look for the file's "signature", so-called "magic bytes" which are generally at the very beginning of the file. Based on [this list of file signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures), a pdf file (for example) should contain the following (hexadecimal) bytes in the following order:

> 25 50 44 46

Which corresponds to this string (in the ISO 8859-1 character encoding)

> %PDF

The attachment body is base64 encoded, which is inconvenient for us because each character in a base64 string is 6 bits (2^6 = 64). We want the first 4 bytes (32 bits), and 32/6 = 5 + 1/3. We can't easily take the 2 highest-order bits, so we'll need to do a bit of work to check to see if a given attachment is "really" a pdf.

Some example code:

```
// Given an Attachment attToTest, trying to gain more confidence that it is a PDF file.
// First, let's convert the attachment body to hex, where each character is a nibble
//   (i.e. 4 bits, or half a byte)
String hexBody = EncodingUtil.convertToHext(EncodingUtil.base64Decode(attToTest.Body));

// Decoding and converting the entire attachment body can possibly consume a lot of
//   your CPU limit.
// Might be worth it to only convert a portion of the body.
// That could be done like this...
// String hexBody = EncodingUtil.convertToHext(EncodingUtil.base64Decode(attToTest.Body.substring(0,11));
// This will return more data than needed, but it works out nicely.
// 12 base64 characters = 72 bits = 9 hexadecimal characters.
// This would need to be adjusted based on the length of the magic bytes, and their offset
//   into the file (usually 0)

// Compare the first 4 bytes/8 hexadecimal characters
Boolean isPDF = hexBody.startsWith('25504446');
```

Expanding that example to be more general is where things get more complicated. I'm not going to write out the code for it, but it would require storing the offsets and magic byte sequences in a collection or two (or three), and iterating over the possible file types. You'd also likely want to only transcode a portion of the attachment body to hex (how much would be determined by the max offset + max magic byte length).

### The takeaway

The easiest route is probably just to trust Salesforce, and use the `ContentType` field of the incoming `Attachment`.

You need to balance ease of implementation with the degree of certainty/security that you need to provide.

Also, realize that, just because you've done your best to verify the file type, you can't be certain that the file itself is not harmful. It is possible, for example to craft a 'GIF' file that contains a PHP payload. While this particular issue wouldn't be an issue in Salesforce, I'm sure there are other vulnerabilities that would.

I'll end with a best practice for upload security. Use a whitelist (things you know you want to accept) rather than a blacklist (things you want to explicitly block). The reason for this is that there can (and will) be new file formats that come up in the future. You can't possibly know all of them, and if you miss one, you open yourself up to attack.

Using a whitelist, on the other hand, explicitly defines what you will allow. Anything else (including all formats yet to be created, and current formats you are unaware of) is rejected. It may mean more work to maintain (you need to explicitly list everything you want to allow, and add new items as they come up), but it is demonstrably more secure.